# Generating only well-typed terms when testing semantics using PLT-Redex

Tags: racket, semantics, plt-redex

I'm new to racket and I'm specially interested in using redex. I've done a small model for typed arithmetic expressions as found in Pierce's types and programming languages book. The code is at the following gist: https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/e0fd3e1e3ff017b614dcfeee9f9154e0

When I tried to test properties like progress and preservation, I would like to check how much of the code is covered by tests so I ran the following, as in amb tutorial:

```
(let ([c (make-coverage red)])
     (parameterize ([relation-coverage (list c)])
     (check-reduction-relation
      red
      (λ (E) (progress-holds? E)))
      (covered-cases c)))
```

But, it returns

```
'(("E-if-false" . 0) ("E-if-true" . 0) ("E-iszero-suc" . 0) 
  ("E-iszero-zero" . 0) ("E-pred-suc" . 0) ("E-pred-zero" . 0))
```

which means that no rule of the semantics is ever executed, right? I'm thinking that the problem is racket is generating random terms that aren't necessarily well-typed.

My question: Is there a way to specify how to generate only well-typed terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries and redoing this little exercise a couple of types I got a plausible solution (the complete code is at the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/c307e0e7fd33a25ce1852a414a99978a)). The main point to generate only well-typed terms is to constrain redex generator using a `#:satisfying` clause, like the `progress` property test below:

```
(define (progress)
  (let ([c (make-coverage eval-tyexp)])
    (parameterize ([relation-coverage (list c)])
        (redex-check TyExp 
               #:satisfying (types e t) 
               (progress-holds? (term e)))
        (covered-cases c))))
```

The line `#:satisfying (types e t)` says that only expressions `e` that judgment `types e t` holds should be considered.